# C# (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel), Save Data as Excel 2003 File(xls)

Tags: c#, excel

I was able to create the code which save the data to a excel file which extension is "xlsx".
However, I need find a way to export the data into an old excel file format which extension is "xls".

Any simple way I can implement this?

Here is my code :

```
wb.SaveAs(fileName, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, false, false, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlUserResolution, true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

Thanks for reading this.

Comment: I think you can use `Excel.XLFileFormat.xlExcel8`

Comment: @JonathanWillcok Thanks for you answer. I have tested both Excel.XLFileFormat.xlExcel8 and Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, and they are working well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this code :

```
wb.SaveAs(fileName, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```